# Add new record to existing table in MS Access DB

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use a Command button in a Form to add a new record to an existing table but I'm not getting it to perform.

```
Private Sub AddRecord_Click()
'On Error GoTo Err_AddRecord_Click
 
 Dim AddMandant As DAO.Database
 Dim rstMandanten As DAO.Recordset
 Set AddMandant = CurrentDb
 Set rstMandanten = AddMandant.OpenRecordset("Mandantenliste")

 rstMandanten.AddNew
 rstMandanten.Update
 'rstMandanten.Close
 'Set rstMandanten = Nothing
 'DoCmd.Close"
```

I'm stuck and can't find the error...can anyone assist ?

Could also do this without creating a recordset and simply do
DoCmd.OpenTable "Mandantenliste" acEdit ?

v/r
Banyan

Comment: Bind the form to that table. Then you simply can move to a new record. Zero code. That how Access works.

Comment: What does "not getting it to perform" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? No, don't open tables and queries for user data entry/edit - only forms. Why not use BOUND form? If you don't want bound form and don't want to open recordset, can use `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO ..."` method.

Comment: And if your form actually is BOUND (RecordSource property is set) to target table, then why would you populate with a recordset? And fault with your code is it is not actually populating fields, like: `rstMandanten!fieldname = Me.textboxname`.

Comment: Yes, it means "nothing happens"

OK, I'll try to bind it to a form for editing...and like you said I wouldn't have to create a rechord set.